# nUnit's results are not displayed in SonarQube

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, nunit-3.0

I'm using SonarQube and Jenkins. In Jenkins, I check the unit tests with nUnit and the coverage with opencover. The opencover's report is displayed in Sonar but **the nunit's report is not**.

[image: Coverage is displayed]

[image: Unit tests are not displayed]

I followed the instructions at : [Analysing with SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) and at : [Unit Test Execution Results Import](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389772#UnitTestExecutionResultsImport(C#,VB.NET)-NUnit)

My "Begin Analysis and SonarQube for MSBuild" args :

```
/d:sonar.sources="Foo.Bar.Business, Foo.Bar.Data, Foo.Bar.Web, Foo.Bar.FileGen, Foo.Bar.FileInt, Foo.Bar.Revision"
/d:sonar.binaries="Build/Foo.Bar.Business.dll, Build/Foo.Bar.Data.dll, Build/Foo.Bar.Web.dll, Build/Foo.Bar.FileGen.exe, Build/Foo.Bar.FileInt.exe, Build/Foo.Bar.Revision.exe, Build/Foo.Bar.TableauDeBord.exe"
/d:sonar.exclusions="Foo.Bar.Web/Scripts/JQuery/**/*, Foo.Bar.Web/Scripts/MomentJS/**/*, Foo.Bar.Web/Scripts/CanvasJS/**/*, Foo.Bar.Web/Scripts/JQueryUi/**/*, Foo.Bar.Web/Scripts/DataTables/**/*, Foo.Bar.Web/Content/**/*, Foo.Bar.Web/App_Start/**/*, Foo.Bar.Data/Model/**/*, Model/**/*, **/AssemblyInfo.cs, **/*Test.cs, Foo.Bar.Test.Web/**/*, Foo.Bar.JeuTest/**/*, Foo.Bar.Gestion.Web/**/*, **/*.js"
/d:sonar.tests="Foo.Bar.Test"
/d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="D:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/Bar/reports/opencovertests.xml"
/d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths="D:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/Bar/reports/TestResult.xml"
```

My "after msbuild"'s command (windows) :

```
MKDIR "%WORKSPACE%\reports"
MKDIR "%WORKSPACE%\reports-history"

SET COV_PTH="D:\Programmes\opencover.4.6.519"
SET TOOL_PATH="D:\Programmes\NUnit-3.4.1"
SET RPT_PATH="D:\Programmes\ReportGenerator"

%COV_PTH%\OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"%TOOL_PATH%\bin\nunit3-console.exe" -targetargs:"Build\Foo.Bar.Test.dll -result:reports\TestResult.xml;format=nunit2" -filter:"+[Foo.Bar.*]*  -[Foo.Bar.Test]* -[Foo.Bar.Data]Foo.Bar.Data.Model.*" -register -output:"reports\opencovertests.xml"

%RPT_PATH%\ReportGenerator.exe "-reports:reports\opencovertests.xml" "-targetdir:reports-ReportGenerator" "-historydir:reports-history"
```

Versions :

- Jenkins : 2.74
- SonarQube : 6.5
- SonarQube scanner for MSBuild :3.0.2.656
- SonarQube Scanner : 3.0.3.778
- SonarC# plugin : 6.4.1
- OpenCover : 4.6.519
- nUnit : 3.4.1
- MSBuild : 14

Comment: What's the version of your Sonar C# plugin? The support for NUnit came with the latest version - 6.4.

Comment: @Valeri-SonarSourceTeam 6.4.1

Comment: @Valeri-SonarSourceTeam Do you have any idea of what going on? Do you want more information?

Comment: @Valeri-SonarSourceTeam One year later, the problem is still there...

Answer (score 0):

When calling OpenCover.Console.exe you need to use parameter+value:
`-register:user` instead of `-register` only.
In same command line, be sure to be located in folder `D:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/Bar/`, where the report is stored finally.